# How can I receive the right data with a query that contains a filter and child columns

Tags: odata

I want to receive orders with some data based on the date, this works fine until I add an nested expand to an expanded column combined with the data filter on the parent.

```
odata/SaleOrder?$filter=DateDelivery gt 2022-09-01T00:00:00.000Z&$top=10&$expand=Customer,OrderRules($expand=Product)
```

[image: Not working with data filter]

When I'm using another filter it just works fine:

```
odata/SaleOrder?$filter=Number eq 'VK20200310074'&$top=10&$expand=Customer,OrderRules($expand=Product)
```

[image: Working with this filter]

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong or does someone have a suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I fixed it by selecting some properties of Products.
I am still not sure what went wrong, but at least I can continue.

```
odata/SaleOrder?$filter=DateDelivery gt 2022-09-01T00:00:00.000Z&$expand=Customer,OrderRules($expand=Product($select=Oid,Name,Description))
```

[image]